# Spring Boot Rest: avoid request rejecting, consume everything

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, http-post

Good day SO. I want my controller to consume any type of request, disregarding if it is correct or not. I do this for testing purposes. Everything is fine, unless request headers and request body don't match. For instance, my controller can't handle request with `Content-Type` header set to `multipart/form-data` and empty request body. I face "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found" exception and 500 response. It is being thrown somewhere inside core.

I looked for solution, but I didn't find any relevant article, as people are looking for ways to fix faulty requests, and I need a way to consume faulty requests and avoid exception raising.

How can I consume both regular and faulty requests? Any method will suffice, as long as I will be able to fetch body from request and log it. Probably I need to get to the lower abstraction layer.

Comment: You probably want to just extend `HttpServlet` and implement the `service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` method to set the response status and return.

Comment: @StephenC thanks. I managed to create a bean with my servlet and implement the required functionality.